# How to make slave is in sync with master in tungsten replication?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, tungsten-replicator

we are using Tungsten master to slave replication in MySQL.
we have configured this setup very long back.
from last week onwards  slave is in lagging with master around 5 to 10 binary files.
we have checked the N/W connectivity it is fine b/w master and slave.

we are not understanding why lagging is keep on increase?

How to  make slave is in sync with master in tungsten replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try *mk-slave-prefatch*

Slave prefetch is an increasingly popular technique for speeding up native MySQL replication, with several tools already published to enable it, such as *mk-slave-prefetch* and *Replication Booster*.  Tungsten Replicator is now joining the fray.   This article explains how our implementation works, how to install and tune it, and how well it performs compared to unaided MySQL native replication as well as Tungsten parallel replication.

For more information on this please refer: 
http://scale-out-blog.blogspot.in/2012/02/solving-replication-lag-with-tungsten.html